# remove special characters without removing space in between words

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

[image: the text will look like as shown in the image]

By using above logic I am trying to remove space from starting and ending of the sentence and removing special characters. It's removing space last and starting and removing special characters and also removing space in between word to word.But I don't want to remove space in between word to word.

Ex:1234whitegreen

Expected output: 1234 white green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"String".squeeze(' ').gsub(/, /, ',').gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z,\r\n ]/i, '').strip**

**gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z ]/, '')** will remove all special character without start end spaces.

**strip** will remove start and end space from string.